# How do I apply a local/relative rotation to a transform?

Tags: c++, rotation, transform, physics

I'm writing a simple physics component in my C++ engine, using the GLM math library, and any rotations I apply are done in world space, i.e. each rotation is applied along the global X, Y, and Z axes, no matter which way the object is facing. I am applying a torque to my object, and using that to calculate a rotation amount for each axis.

I add the torque via a call to the AddTorque function, which uses the object's transform to apply it in a relative direction. For example, for pitching the object (rotation around the X axis):

`AddTorque(m_transform[0] * 50.0f);`

The calculation code itself, where the rotation is not local/relative (m_acceleration, m_velocity, m_torque, etc, are all of the form glm::vec3, and the transform of the type glm::mat4):

```
void PhysicsComponent::Update(float a_deltaTime)
{
    ///////////
    // rotation
    glm::mat4 transform = m_parent->GetTransform();
    glm::vec3 rotVec = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);

    m_angularAcceleration = m_torque / m_momentOfInertia;
    m_angularVelocity += m_angularAcceleration * a_deltaTime;
    rotVec += m_angularVelocity * a_deltaTime;

    transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotVec.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotVec.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotVec.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));

    ///////////
    // position
    glm::vec3 position = transform[3].xyz;

    m_acceleration = m_force / m_mass;
    m_velocity += m_acceleration * a_deltaTime;
    position += m_velocity * a_deltaTime;

    transform[3].xyz = position;

    m_parent->SetTransform(transform);

    m_force.x = 0;
    m_force.y = 0;
    m_force.z = 0;

    m_torque.x = 0;
    m_torque.y = 0;
    m_torque.z = 0;

    rotVec = glm::vec3(0,0,0);
}
```